# How to write if else statement in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

See I can write some code in PHP I want to write the same code in laravel-8 how can I?
My PHP code

```
<td>
<?PHP
   if($Runs>0 and $Balls==0){
      echo $Runs*100;
   }elseif($Balls>0 and $Runs==0){
      echo $Balls*$Runs;
   }elseif($Balls==0 and $Runs==0){
      echo $Balls*$Runs;
   }
    elseif($Runs>0 and $Balls>=0){
      echo $Runs/$Balls*100;
   }
?>
</td>
```

I want to write this same code in laravel-8
This is what I can do

```
<td>
{{ $value->runs/$value->balls*100 }}
</td>
```

I can't write if else condition there How can I?

Comment: In blade template use `@if(something) your code @endif`. Refer to [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#if-statements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use as like below.

```
@if($Runs>0 and $Balls==0)
        {{ $Runs*100 }}
@elseif ($Balls>0 and $Runs==0)
        {{ $Balls*$Runs }}
@else
  your else code
@endif
```

You can check all blade template condition in [document](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#if-statements) to